# whats is wrong in this basic method Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, get, set

i'm newbe in this programming language (in almost too), i just wanna use a "if and else" with getter and setter methods, i'm doing a basic RPG for learning purpose.
I've a character x, and all i wanna do is; if the life of this character is lower than 0 revive this character,else just increase his life. This is my 
code.

```
public Skill bless(Character x) {
   if (0>= x.getCurrentHp()) {
       x.getCurrentHp() == x.getHp() * 3/4;
   }
   else if (x.getCurrentHp() > 0) {
       x.getCurrentHp() =+ x.getHp() * 1/2;
   }
   return x;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the behavior that the method is giving you? You're not telling us this most important bit of information.

Comment: In the first branch of the if-statement you are using `==` where you should use `=` I guess.

Comment: I'm sure that integer division is not what you had in mind.  3/4 == 0 when you use integer division, not 0.75.  I'll bet you're surprised by that outcome.

Comment: @JanSchaefer you are absolutely wrong. It won't change anything. Read my answer why.

Comment: And just for the record: it is bad practice to **update** your incoming parameter; and to also return it. Dont mix things. Either manipulate your parameter (see as "inout"; or return an "updated" value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue is in these lines:

```
x.getCurrentHp() == x.getHp() * 3/4;
x.getCurrentHp() =+ x.getHp() * 1/2;
```

You have to use methods like:

```
x.setCurrentHp(x.getHp() * 3/4);
x.setCurrentHp(x.getHp() * 1/2);
```

Under the hood methods `setCurrentHp` / `getCurrentHp` should be like the following:

```
public class Character {
    private int currentHp;
    // ... other methods and fields

    public void setCurrentHp(int hp){ currentHp = hp; }

    public int getCurrentHp(){ return hp; }
}
```

Because when you call `x.getCurrentHp()` it simply returns the value. And then you are just assigning `x.getHp() * 1/2` to that value.

As a tutorial, you can refer to [official examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) of `getter`/`setter` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
x.getCurrentHp() == x.getHp() * 3/4
```

Use

```
x.setCurrentHp(x.getHp() * 3/4)
```

Notice I change it to a Set method.  Assuming this method has already been created.